# Rxjs - How to subscribe only one time after multiple http service?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an issue with rxjs operators. I have an observable of array of strings

```
role$: Observable<string[]>;
```

I created a function and I need to use all of that string to call an http service using each string as parameter.

```
  getDetails() {
    this.role$.pipe(concatMap(role =>{
      return this.myService.getDetails(role)
    })).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

I write this function but I need to complete all the http call before subscription. I need to complete all the calls and in subscription I have to create a logic only one time. In the function I wrote I have multiple console.log based on the number of server calls I do. I would only one response that contains an array of responses of each server call

Comment: concatMap doesn't break down the resulting array into its items, it just builds on the pipe. So `role` is still a `string[]` here, which is why this doesn't work. What you want to do is to apply the array method `.map` on the resulting role array and do a forkJoin of all of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) from the RxJS library.

```js
  getDetails() {
    this.role$.pipe(
      mergeMap(
        roles => forkJoin(roles.map(role => myService.handle(role))))
      ).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }
```